# In UICollectionView, collapse animation is imperfect, with no height shrinking animation for the hidden item

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview, uistackview

Based on the problem described in

[How to achieve smooth expand/ collapse animation in UICollectionView with dynamic cell height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71895741/how-to-achieve-smooth-expand-collapse-animation-in-uicollectionview-with-dynami)

and the improvement mentioned in

[Change default StackView animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71622706/change-default-stackview-animation/71711672#71711672)

I had made the following changes

1. Added an inner `UIView`, for collapse and expand purpose
2. The inner `UIView` will have attribute **Clips to Bounds** set to true
3. A vertical `UIStackView` placed in the inner `UIView`, with bottom constraint set to **high**.
4. I really don't know. For unknown reason, the bottom constraint of the parent `UIStackView` need to be **low**, in order for the UI to stay at top, during collapse animation.

This is my outcome.

---

[image]

As you can see,

1. The expand animation works just fine!
2. For **collapse animation**, the inner `UIView` will disappear immediately, without any animation.

Do you have any idea, why there is no hidden animation during collapse?

Here's the code which perform collapse/ expand.

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return shops.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let collectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell else {
            fatalError()
        }
        
        let shop = shops[indexPath.item]
        
        collectionViewCell.title.text = shop.title
        collectionViewCell._description.text = shop.description
        
        if isExpanded[indexPath.item] {
            collectionViewCell.innerView.isHidden = false
        } else {
            collectionViewCell.innerView.isHidden = true
        }
        
        return collectionViewCell
    }

}
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        for i in (0..<isExpanded.count) {
            if i == indexPath.item {
                // ensure always visible
                isExpanded[i] = true
            } else {
                // set all other rows to false
                isExpanded[i] = false
            }
            if let c = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)) as? CollectionViewCell {
                c.innerView.isHidden = !isExpanded[i]
            }
        }
        collectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

What I have tried so far is

1. Use a zero height constraint to activate/ deactivate, to replace `isHidden`
2. Use `UIView.animate`

But, the inner `UIView` will disappear immediately, without any height shrinking animation.

Do you have idea how I can fix this? Thanks.

Here's the code to illustrate the problem - https://github.com/yccheok/shop-dialog/tree/c399bca163096ad27de7de866af5d2de370a8afb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment to you on another question, rarely do we find a "one size fits all" solution.

Instead of fighting with the default behaviors when setting `.isHidden` on a stack view's arranged subviews, here's a different approach.

Use **two** bottom constraints:

- One from the bottom of the "top / always-visible" UI elements
- One from the bottom of the "show/hide" elements (their container view)

Set the `.priority` of the **second** constraint to 750 (`.defaultHigh`).

When you want the cell to be "collapsed" set the `.priority` of the **first** constraint to 751 (`.defaultHigh + 1`).

When you want the cell to be "expanded" set the `.priority` of the **first** constraint to 749 (`.defaultHigh - 1`).

To animate the expand/collapse effect, wrap `performBatchUpdates` in a `UIView.animate` block.

I forked your GitHub repo here - https://github.com/DonMag/shop-dialog - and added this approach as "V2" so you can inspect it and see the differences.

Comment: Thank you @DonMag. I took me several reads to understand the concept behind. That is a very creative way to make use of priority. I try your work as baseline, by using zero height constraint on inner view. It works well too.